# Regex to prevent set of characters

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, regex-group

I need to prevent user from entering the following set of chars:
~ " # % & * : < > ? / \ { | } .

Important is that, anything else will be allowed, but only the characters shown above will be forbidden.

Currently, I'm using the following regex but this does also forbid for example ! sign.

```
  private static folderRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+[ßüÜöÖäÄ\w]*$/;
```

Comment: Why not `/^[^~"#%&*:<>?/\\{|}]*$/`?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the set of characters in an inverse set and add a `^` and a `$` to stretch the pattern to the full length of the input.

```
 private static folderRegex = /^[^~"#%&*:<>?\/\\{|}]+$/;
```

Comment: this expression allows to enter "\" but rest of the checks pass. if you could fix that i could accept this as the right answer

Comment: @AhmetEroğlu yes, was missing an escape, thanks for pointing that out